# ElasticSearch Index Analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data

I'm using org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository to save indexes. I want to use Ngram analyzer for indexing, how can i add custom index analyzer?

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/blurays " -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "nGram_filter": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20,
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nGram_filter"
               ]
            },

         }
      }
   },
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to use it in a mapping field.

I wrote up a blog post for [Qbox](https://qbox.io/) about getting started with Ngrams, which you can find here:

[An Introduction to Ngrams in Elasticsearch](https://qbox.io/blog/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch)

Here is the TLDR, which will hopefully help answer your immediate question:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "edge_ngram_filter": {
               "type": "edge_ngram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "edge_ngram_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "text_field": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
               "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```