# add analyzer for index with elasticsearch and nestjs

Tags: elasticsearch, nestjs

I'm using [@nestjs/elasticsearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/elasticsearch) and want to use bulgarian analyzer, for search it's too easy

```
    const result = await this.elasticsearchService.search<Question>({
      index: this.index,
      query: {
        multi_match: {
          query: text,
          fields: ['body', 'tags.name'],
          analyzer: 'bulgarian',
        },
      },
    });
```

but there is nothing similar available for index, this is the current code

```
    this.elasticsearchService.index<Question>({
      index: this.index,
      id: question.id.toString(),
      document: question,
    });
```

I read from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33219447/2748984 it should be done through mapping, but index method doesn't take mapping as well, here is what index interface is

```
export interface IndexRequest<TDocument = unknown> extends RequestBase {
    id?: Id;
    index: IndexName;
    if_primary_term?: long;
    if_seq_no?: SequenceNumber;
    op_type?: OpType;
    pipeline?: string;
    refresh?: Refresh;
    routing?: Routing;
    timeout?: Duration;
    version?: VersionNumber;
    version_type?: VersionType;
    wait_for_active_shards?: WaitForActiveShards;
    require_alias?: boolean;
    document?: TDocument;
}
```

I don't see any of the options is related to mapping or analyzer

Comment: There must be a `this.elasticsearchService.create()` function that allows you to create your index with a specific mapping as in the question you've linked to

Comment: yes that's it, add answer to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a `this.elasticsearchService.create(...)` function that allows you to create your index with a specific mapping as in the [question you've linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33219447/2748984), something similar to this:

```
this.elasticsearchService.indices.create<Question>({
  index: this.index,
  mapping: ...,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the code that actually worked

```
  async indexQuestion(question: Question): Promise<IndexResponse> {
    if (
      !(await this.elasticsearchService.indices.exists({ index: this.index }))
    ) {
      await this.elasticsearchService.indices.create({
        index: this.index,
        mappings: {
          properties: {
            body: {
              type: 'text',
              analyzer: 'bulgarian',
              fields: {
                keyword: {
                  type: 'keyword',
                  ignore_above: 256,
                },
              },
            },
            'tags.name': {
              type: 'text',
              analyzer: 'bulgarian',
              fields: {
                keyword: {
                  type: 'keyword',
                  ignore_above: 256,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });
    }

    return this.elasticsearchService.index<Question>({
      index: this.index,
      id: question.id.toString(),
      document: question,
    });
  }
```